# PHP click counter not working

Tags: php, counter

i'm a student in programming and we currently are seeing the PHP language. I'd need a click counter in PHP to know how many times a user clicked on a link, and then print it, so here's my code :

```
$i=0;

$url = ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

switch($url){

case 'action=add':
    $i++;
    break;
case'action=remove':
    $i--;
    break;

}
echo "you clicked $i times";
```

I have 2 links on my index.php with href = 'action=add' or 'action=remove'.
The way i see it is, everytime i click on a link, it add the query string to my url and therefore should increment or decrement $i, but it doesn't. my $i is either equal to 1 or -1. Any ideas what's wrong ?

Comment: Sounds like you're wanting to use [tag:javascript] instead

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is beacause you don't store anywhere the value of $i.
So each time you call the script $i is initialised with the value 0 instead to start from the old value.

Answer (score 0):

You wanna do it by simply passing it via parameters in the URL ?

Using the counter inside the parameter:

```
$counter = 0;

// Check if the parameter 'c' as passed and its an numeric 
if (!empty($_GET["c"]) && is_numeric($_GET["c"]))
    $counter = $_GET["c"];


$action = isset($_GET["action"]) ? $_GET["action"] : null;

if ($action == null)
    die("invalid action");

switch ($action)
{
    case "add":
    {
        $counter++;
        break;
    }

    case "remove":
    {
        // Decrease only when its greater then 0
        if ($counter > 0)
            $counter--;
        break;
    }

    default:
    {
        die("You can only 'add' or 'remove'");
        break;
    }
}

echo "You clicked " . $counter . " times";
```

Or using it in session (which saves it for period of time):

```
// If the session haven't started yet, start it
if (!session_id())
    session_start();

$counter = 0;

// Check if the 'c' saved in the sessions and its an numeric 
if (!empty($_SESSION["c"]) && is_numeric($_SESSION["c"]))
    $counter = $_SESSION["c"];


$action = isset($_GET["action"]) ? $_GET["action"] : null;

if ($action == null)
    die("invalid action");

switch ($action)
{
    case "add":
    {
        $counter++;
        break;
    }

    case "remove":
    {
        // Decrease only when its greater then 0
        if ($counter > 0)
            $counter--;
        break;
    }

    default:
    {
        die("You can only 'add' or 'remove'");
        break;
    }
}

// Save the new counter for next time
$_SESSION["c"] = $counter;

echo "You clicked " . $counter . " times";
```